# Leer fichero CSV en Python

Tags: python, csv

Estoy tratando de leer un fichero csv (PATRONES.csv) en python utilizando este código:

```
   location= r'PATRONES.csv'
    patrones = pd.read_csv(location,header=None,names= ['nombre','tablaBBDD','descripcion'])
```

Y el fichero csv lo que tiene es:

```
Dia del Mes,dbdiames,ww

Dia de la Semana,dbdiasemana, DD

Mes del Año,dbmes,DD

Nuevos Maximos a 15 Días,dbnewmax15days,ww

Nuevos Maximos Diarios,dbnewmaxday,ww

Nuevos Maximos Semanales,dbnewmaxweek,ww

Estacionalidad,dbseasonality,ww

Ventanas Estacionales,dbseasonalwindows,ww
```

y me sale un error:

> File "", line 2, in 
> patrones = pd.read_csv(location,header=None,names=['nombre','tablaBBDD','descripcion'])
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
> line 678, in parser_f
> return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
> line 446, in _read
> data = parser.read(nrows)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
> line 1036, in read
> ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
> line 1848, in read
> data = self._reader.read(nrows)
>
> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 876, in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
>
> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 891, in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
>
> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 968, in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
>
> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1094, in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
>
> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1141, in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
>
> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1240, in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
>
> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1256, in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
>
> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1494, in
> pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position
> 9: invalid continuation byte

¿A qué es debido y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A juzgar por el error, tu archivo .csv está codificado en un formato de 8 bits, posiblemente `cp-1254` si ha sido generado en Windows. En cualquier caso, si el juego de caracteres que contiene se limita a vocales acentuadas, eñes, y resto de símbolos ASCII (que es lo habitual), esa codificación es compatible con `iso-8859-15`, también llamada `latin9`.

Tienes que especificar ese *encoding* a pandas:

```
  location= r'PATRONES.csv'
  patrones = pd.read_csv(location, header=None, encoding='latin9',
                         names= ['nombre','tablaBBDD','descripcion'])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ese era el problema. He incluído tu código y funciona perfectamente. Gracias y un saludo

Comment: @evalde Si el problema ha sido resuelto por el compañero, marca como correcta y puntúa positivamente la respuesta. Un saludo!

Comment: Muchas gracias, ese era el problema que tenia, la codificación me estaba complicando la vida.