# Cómo puedo leer un archivo .csv en visual studio code usando python?

Tags: python, python-3.8

Soy nuevo usando este editor. He tratado de abrir un archivo adjunto el cual necesito para mi código, lo guardo en la ruta de mi código y utilizo la función with open ('nombre del archivo') pero visual studio dice que no hay un archivo con ese nombre en la ruta (cabe resaltar que yo copio y pego el nombre, por lo que no hay error escribiéndolo)

Comment: Hola Andrés, bienvenido a [es.so]. Sin ver la estructura de archivos de tu proyecto y cómo llamas exactamente a `open` va ser difícil ayudar, las causas posibles son muchas, uso de rutas relativas cuando el directorio de trabajo del script ha cambiado, extensiones ocultas de archivos en Windows, cadena de la ruta mal formada por contener '\' sin escapar, ruta directamente incorrecta, etc. Pasar a `open`  el nombre (con la extensión obviamente) funcionará si el directorio de trabajo del script es el mismo que el del código fuente en ese momento.

Comment: Hola Andres bienvenido, podrias compatir el codigo que estas usando

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Leer fichero CSV en Pyhton](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230764/leer-fichero-csv-en-pyhton)

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir un .csv, resulta más cómodo utilizar la librería PANDAS, comúnmente como `import pandas as pd`. No sé si Visual Studio ya venga con esta librería instalada, pero de no ser así te dejo el link: https://pandas.pydata.org/

Para abrir el .csv con esa librería basta con teclear:

```
[variable] = pd.read_csv('[nombre de tu archivo].csv')
```

Si aún así necesitas usar la `with open [nombre de tu archivo].csv`, asegurate bien que tenga la extensión .csv dentro del *string* en el que lo especificas.

Espero que te haya funcionado.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un modulo disponible para leer archivos csv

```
import csv

# Ruta... (misma carpeta)
filename = 'file.csv' 

with open(filename) as f:
    
    # Crear objeto iterable
    header = next(f)

    # Imprimir 1era fila.
    for h in header:
        print(h, end='')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esto si se pudo abrir