# Problema al importar un csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Intentando importar un csv con pandas escribo:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('DFs/Vtv_1_ok.csv')
```

y al ejecutar el código me sale el siguiente error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 8: invalid continuation byte
```

¿Alguien me podria explicar a que se debe?

Ya importe el csv con el botón de importar del explorador de variables y me funciono bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que tienes el mismo problema como aquí: [Leer fichero CSV en Pyhton](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230764/leer-fichero-csv-en-pyhton)

Puedes usar `encoding = 'latin9'`

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('DFs/Vtv_1_ok.csv', encoding = 'latin9')
```

Comment: Esto soluciono mi problema, muchas gracias.